# Python - Return Google Cloud Storage - Return a File

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, fastapi, google-cloud-run

I need to build an API layer to expose a set of files stored within a Private Google Cloud Storage bucket, using Python. I may be using FastAPI for this.
The API would most likely be hosted as GCP Run application.

Could I get some guidance on the best practices for this?

My thinking was, from within the Cloud function to return a FastAPI File Response 
e.g. `return FileResponse(some_file_path)`

Is this a valid approach?

Comment: What will be the size of your files?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, the sizes vary from 1 to 100MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have file of "moderate" size, you can load the file from Cloud Storage and serve it directly with your service (Cloud Run, or Cloud Functions, or other).

In case of large file, above a few Mb, it's recommended to use [signedURL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). On the client request, you generate a signed request and you reply it. For a better experience, you can set the HTTP code 307 (temporary redirect) to indicate to the client to query the new (signed) URL